# Repeat elements in mPDF on every page

Tags: mpdf

is there a possibility to repeat elements on every page without using the header- or footerelements on mPDF?
I want a punch- and foldmark on every page but I have als on header and footer on every page.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a background image using the `@page` CSS property:

```
@page {
    background: url(<?= __DIR__ ?>/images/background.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-image-resize: 6;
}
```

That background will now display on all pages.

Alternatively, use absolute positioning in a header / footer to get the desired results. If you already have a header / footer, just absolute position those elements as well ([a header / footer cannot currently contain both absolute and non-absolute positioned elements](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/791#issuecomment-400519787)).

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution not exactly what I prefer but works better than nothing :).
I would prefer if its possible to use plain HTML-Elements.